# Como criar exceção no mod_expires do htaccess

Tags: htaccess, cache

Tenho um site que uso o `mod_expires` para salvar em cache, mas eu não queria aplicar pra todas as páginas, porque a página inicial por exemplo, é dinâmica, muda todo dia.

Tem como eu criar uma regra de exceção para não aplicar para determinadas páginas?

Esse é o código que uso no htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# HTML
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se for Apache 2.4 pode usar [**`<If>`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if), usando [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) por exemplo:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /^\/caminho-exemplo\/foo\/bar\//">
    # se começar com /caminho-exemplo/foo/bar/
    # algo aqui
</If>
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /^\/user\/[a-zA-Z\-]+\/?$/">
    # se casar/match com /user/<nome do usuário de A a Z e hifén>/
    # algo aqui
</ElseIf>
<ElseIf "Outra IF aqui">
    # algo aqui
</ElseIf>
<Else>
    # algo aqui em exceção a todos anteriores
</Else>
```